# VB.NET: Cannot access function from reference

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I have a project, `Project 1`, that I've included in another project (`Project 2`).  I'm trying to access a Function from `Project 2` in `Project 1`.  I can navigate to the function in my solution from `Project 2`, but when trying to access it from my file in `Project 1` I can't seem to get access.

I've also tried adding a reference but, I get a message saying I already have a reference to `Project 2` in `Project 1`; which I guess happened when I added it to the solution.  Can anyone help me solve this issue? Thanks!

**EDIT**
Perhaps I explained the structure of my solution poorly.  Here is a "visual" representation of my Solution Explorer...

```
Solution 'Project1' (2 projects)
  Project1
     Folders
        Files
  Project2
     Folders
        Files
```

Comment: Sounds like circular reference, which isn't possible. You'll have to add third project, put the common functions there and reference that third project in both "Project 1" and "Project 2".

Comment: hmm seems kinda strange to do that unless I'm just misunderstanding you.  If I have Project1 that I'm working on and only included Project2 to get access to functions within why would I need to create a third proejct?

Comment: Because it sounds like you are also trying to access a function that is inside  Project1 from within Project2.

Comment: I don't think I have... I've made an edit to my question that will hopefully show the Solution Explorer. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Explain your references. Look at the References of P1. Does it contains a reference to P2? Look at the References of P2. Does it contains a reference to P1?. In the first case you can access the functions of P2 from P1, in the latter you can access the functions of P1 from P2. You can't have both P1->P2 AND P2->P1

Comment: Is the function and its parent `Public` and not `Friend`? Modules and classes are declared as `Friend` by default. That means that they can only be accessed from the containing assembly / project.

Answer (score 2):

- Make sure that you have added a reference to the project you want to access, in the project you want to access it from. You can do this by right clicking the project in the solution explorer > Add Reference.. > Click the solution tab > Check the project you want to access > OK.
- Make sure that the class you want to access is "Public".
- Remember to use the full name of whatever you are trying to access in Project2. As example, if you have a class named "MyClass", which is inside of a namespace named "SomeClasses", you would have to target "MyClass" like this: *Project2.SomeClasses.MyClass*.
  You can also use the "Import" keyword so that you don't have to write the full path each time.

Comment: You can access modules if they are public. Your last point is not correct: firstly it assumes that `Project1` is the default namespace for Project1 and that the class is not in another namespace. Instead you should advise to use the fully qualified name (including namespaces) or to use `Imports` statements. Edit your answer and I'll give you a +1.